# Blocked by CORS policy with a React / ES6 Promise POST request

Tags: reactjs, post, promise, cors, es6-promise

I'm making a POST request to my API but getting returns a '**blocked by CORS policy**' message.

The API is expecting a XML data which I have contained in a XML file which is being imported in to this request in the **exampleAccountSettings** value in the code example below.

The message I'm currently getting being returned from the API is this

> Access to fetch at 'https://exampleAPI.com/api/settings/import' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

And here's my Promise

```
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const requestUrl = https://exampleAPI.com/api/settings/import;
      const init = {
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'cors',
        headers: {
          authorization: localStorage.token,
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(exampleAccountSettings)
    };
    return fetch(requestUrl, init).then((response) => {
      log.debug('importAccountSettings(): response:', response);
    })
  });
```

All I've seen similar to this question state I need to add something like **"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"** to specify that access is allowed but this seems to have no effect.

So is there a different approach for ES6 / React or maybe it's something I have misunderstood? Any advice welcome or if someone can point me in the direction of some research I'd be very appreciative!

Answer (score 1):

You need to be able to control the server-side response headers from https://exampleAPI.com. If you don't own the domain or can't control the headers, then you're out of luck.

For security reasons, JavaScript can only make xhr calls to the same domain (or cross-domain if the right header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is present and allows your domain - or wildcard *).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS